# PHP DomDocument - new line symbol gets added when calling loadHTML()

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm running the following snippet of code in PHP:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = "<html><body>Test<br></body></html>";
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$loadedContent = $doc->saveHTML();
var_dump($loadedContent);
```

What I expect to see is a string identical to `$html` value, since I didn't perform any transformations on the DOM document. However, there is an extra new line character in `var_dump` output

Could you explain where it's coming from? Did I miss to set some options?

Comment: You're "rendering" the HTML as a DOM tree and then generating HTML from the tree. Probably that counts as transformation.

Comment: The document has been parsed into a DOM structure, it doesn't remember the original HTML. When you dump it, it has to recreate the HTML.

Comment: It's adding the newline at the end, after `</html>`. This has no effect, it's like adding or removing trailing zeroes after the decimal point of a number.